# Bond ADSL+ line with Cable Modem line in one single router

Tags: cable, adsl

I need two bond ADSL+ modem with cable modem router at the office so I don't have to switch the line everytime one of them is offline, is there any software/hardware that allows me to bond two physical conections into one at my router, so everyone at the LAN is getting the two of em without having to reconfigure everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the two links are from different ISPs.

You need a router with at least three interface (one for your LAN, one for each of your WAN connections).  Cisco has a feature called Optimized Edge Routing, which lets the router test each path and then choose the one with the best performance.  So it will automatically switch if one path goes down. Other manufacturers have similar features.

You don't "bond" the two links, because that will cause out of order packets and reduce your performance.  You will use one or the other link, depending on the performance of each.

I am assuming the two links are from different ISPs.

Comment: Exactly, they are both from different ISPs, so im gonna search for those Cisco OER enabled routers, thanks buddy!